# Excel doing a file overwrite by itself

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an Excel Macro for the below algorithm:

Steps:

1) Loop through emails in Outlook

2) Download attachments (excel files) to a specific folder

3) Open Excel dashboard template

4) Open saved Attachment (excel file)

5) Copy data from attachment to template

6) Close Attachment

7) Adjust data in template

8) Save template as new Workbook

9) Go to step 3 and proceed with next Attachment

My problem is that in the step 6 the file (Attachment) does not close entirely - it's still visible in Project Explorer so each time i'm saving the Template excel as new Dashboard.xlsx it immediately overwrites it with the Attachment. I have already searched for the solution but all i found is to use `workbooks.close` on the Attachment, which does not work for me.

I have found out that the only way to close the attachment entirely is to close the Template file, so it looks like they are connected in some way.

Here is the code:

```
' this code gets called by a macro that downloads the attachments
Sub update_WB()

Dim main_book, att_book As Workbook
Dim lastrow, firstrow As Long
Dim att_name as string

Workbooks.Open "../template.xlsx"  ‘<- I have shorten the path for the purpose of posting

Set main_book = Application.ActiveWorkbook

main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.UnMerge

Application.Workbooks.Open  "../attachment.xlsx"  ‘<- I have shorten the path for the purpose of posting

Set att_book = ActiveWorkbook

att_book.Worksheets(1).Range("A:BD").Select

Selection.Copy main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A:BD")

att_book.Close ‘<- this is where the attachment should close, but it does not. It only disappears from windows taskbar.

main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate

lastrow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Worksheets("Raw Data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
For firstrow = 1 To 100
    If Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(firstrow, 1).Text = "Date" Then Exit For
Next firstrow

main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells.Select
Selection.UnMerge

main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A" & firstrow & ":BG" & lastrow - 1).Name = "Raw_Data"


‘. 
‘.
‘.
‘. Some data manipulation –> copy, paste, delete, etc. 
‘.
‘.
‘.
‘.     

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    main_book.SaveAs (“../Dashboard_" & Format(Timeserial(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now())),"hhmmss") & ".xlsx") ‘<- I have shorten the path for the purpose of posting. This is where excel does the saving twice – first it saved the main_book and then att_book, both under the same name.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
main_book.Close '<- this is where both of the files close entirely

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the following -

```
Workbooks.Open "../template.xlsx"  ‘<- I have shorten the path for the purpose of posting

Set main_book = Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

With

```
Set main_book = Workbooks.Add(Template:="../template.xlsx")
```

That creates a new wb out of the template rather than just opening the template file.

EDIT:!!

Also consider

```
Application.Workbooks.Open  "../attachment.xlsx"  ‘<- I have shorten the path for the purpose of posting

Set att_book = ActiveWorkbook
```

->

```
Set att_book = Application.Workbooks.Open  "../attachment.xlsx"
```

This avoids unintentional referrals to incorrect open books.

EDIT 2: working parts of the code, runs and saves no errors

```
Sub update_WB()

Dim main_book, att_book As Workbook
Dim lastrow, firstrow As Long
Dim att_name As String

Set main_book = Workbooks.Add(Template:="template.xlsx")  'Corrected



main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.UnMerge

Set att_book = Application.Workbooks.Open("attachment.xlsx")  'Corrected



att_book.Worksheets(1).Range("A:BD").Select

Selection.Copy main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A:BD")

att_book.Close
Set att_book = Nothing 'Added pointer reset, ultimately closes the workbook

main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate

lastrow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Worksheets("Raw Data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
For firstrow = 1 To 100
    If Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(firstrow, 1).Text = "Date" Then Exit For
Next firstrow

main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells.Select
Selection.UnMerge


    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    main_book.SaveAs ("Dashboard_" & Format(TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now())), "hhmmss") & ".xlsx") ''<- I have shorten the path for the purpose of posting. This is where excel does the saving twice – first it saved the main_book and then att_book, both under the same name.
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
main_book.Close
Set mainbook = Nothing 'Ultimately closes the template

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work, the saved file was overwritten by the Attachment.xlsx.

Comment: I refined my answer, please note that you also referred to active workbook in the attachment via active workbook. This type of assignment is very prone to bugs due to not specifically pointing to a certain opened file.

Comment: Still the same. I have tried all combinations below but it didn't work.:

`Set main_book = Workbooks.Open(Template:="../template.xlsx")`

`Set main_book = Workbooks.Add(Template:="../template.xlsx")`

`Set att_book = Application.Workbooks.Open  "../attachment.xlsx"`

`Set att_book = Application.Workbooks.Add "../attachment.xlsx"`

The thing is when I have the attachments already saved on my desktop and then restart the application, the faulty part of macro works perfectly. This is actually the workaround i'm using now - restarting the whole thing after download.

Comment: @PawełSotor Are you running the macro in what file?

Comment: There are 3 files: 

1) File with macro, lets call it "Tool", 

2) Attachment downloaded from outlook containing raw data (att_book). 

3) Dashboard template (main_book). 

I'm running the Tool and it does all the downloading and adjusting. Other files provide the layout and data. Beside the part mentioned in my post the Tool also creates automatic email responds, clears old files, etc, but the only part where it misbehave is saving.

Comment: @PawełSotor I can't think of any other reason for the behavior except there is something re-opening the att_book in the block you have marked as `some data manipulation` att_book closes perfectly in my tests. Or there is a change happening (formula calcultion for ex) in the att_book, that prohibits it from closing with save dialogue? Have you checked if that is the case?

Comment: Yes i have, it didn't work. I even tried att_book.kill but it didn't work. As for the attachment, it's only used to copy the data:

`Set att_book = Application.Workbooks.Add "../attachment.xlsx"

att_book.Worksheets(1).Range("A:BD").Select

Selection.Copy main_book.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A:BD")

att_book.Close `

I forgot to mention it's a company Excel so it's loaded with addins. I have tried to turn all of them off but it didn't help.

Comment: @PawełSotor You could try adding `Set att_book = Nothing` after the `att_book.Close` that should release the pointer. Other than that I can't find much else to be perfected that could cause the problem within the code block itself. I will check on this a bit later, maybe with fresh brains I can find something new..

Comment: I have tried that to. I have tried to rename the attachment, to save it somewhere else, to kill it before and after close, to save it as different file, to copy the content to a third file and then to main_book, to save the main_book twice, I have used literally every trick I know.

Comment: @Wujaszkun I have run the code now multiple times over and it runs perfectly smooth every time no errors. I will add the code with corrections in my answer, check it out and try...